# Unable to set the colour in UINavigation bar - iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set a different colour to the UINavigation bar in the iPhone app. My app is running in iOS 7 and the code snippet which I use is below

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

But the above code is not changing the color of the navigation bar to red. Am I missing something. Can you please help me. Thanks

Comment: where you adding the code delegate file or??

Comment: make sure your `self.navigationController` should not be nil.

Comment: And try `if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7)` instead using array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the below code in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* in your **AppDelegate**

```
if ([self checkOSVersion] >= 7) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
} else {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

- (int)checkOSVersion {

    NSArray *ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    int osVerson = [[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    return osVerson;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding Color for all navigation bar default set below code in appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    return YES;
}
```

or else want to set color for particular view means then use this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

}
```

If you want learn more try this link it is good [check this link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's failing the if statement `if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7)`. I would replace that whole `if statement` with:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 7) {
    // Do the below if you want to set the bar tint color for every UINavigationBar
    // [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    // [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]; 
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO];

 } else {
     // Do the below if you want to set the bar tint color for every UINavigationBar
     // [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
     [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 }
```

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];` will return a `NSString *` that could be anything from `7` to `7.0.1`. Doing `floatValue` will return at least `7.0` as it will append the `0` on the end if it just returns `7` so we want it to always only give us the initial system version of `7` so we need to do `intValue` on the end so it looks like `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue];` forget about the `componentSeperatedByString:` method no need at all for it, it will cause more issues then you want.

You could also do this sort of `if statement`

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0) {
    // Everything above and including iOS 7.0
} else {
    // Everything below iOS 7.0
}
```